# Nativescript background mode

Tags: ionic-framework, background, nativescript, mode

I have a Ionic  app using background mode Cordova plugin (mainly to listen to socket.io even  while in background). I am now redeveloping that app using Nativescript Angular. How can  i achieve the same  background execution (possibly with the same transparent ease of use) in nativescript ? The Cordova plugin, after installation, works trasparently and does not require any change to the app flow...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here are examples how you could implement background services for [Android](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services) / [iOS](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ios-background-execution).